# Show that if A, B, and C are sets then

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that if $A, B$, and $C$ are sets then

$\vert A \cup B \cup C\vert =\vert A\vert +\vert B\vert +\vert C\vert -\vert A\cap B\vert -\vert A\cap C\vert -\vert B\cap C\vert +\vert A\cap B\cap C\vert$

I'm not sure about how to go about solving this.

Comment: Try sketching a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 1):

It's well explained in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).